# Is my print/gets receiving or outputing the wrong type?

Tags: ruby, types, syntax, casting

This is my code:

```
print('What amount would you like to calculate tax for?  ')
subtotal = gets.chomp
taxrate = 0.078
tax = subtotal * taxrate
puts "Tax on $#{subtotal} is $#{tax}, so the grand total is $#{subtotal + tax}."
```

First output: `What amount would you like to calculate tax for?`

Input: `100`.

Final output: `Tax on $100 is $, so the grand total is $100.`

I believe I should be getting a tax rate of `$7.79999999` and a grand total of `107.7999999`.  I'd like to make the code a little better by doing things like stripping the $ from the input, should a user mistakenly enter a $, and rounding up to the nearest cent.  First, I need to understand why I'm not getting any output or addition, though, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us go through your code:

```
subtotal = gets.chomp
```

`gets.chomp` gives you a String so this:

```
tax = subtotal * taxrate
```

is using [`String#*`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-2A) rather than multiplying numbers:

> **str * integer → new_str**
>
> Copy—Returns a new `String` containing *integer* copies of the receiver.

But `taxrate.to_i` will give you zero and `any_string * 0` gives you an empty String. So you're getting exactly what you're asking for, you're simply asking for the wrong thing.

You need to convert `subtotal` to a number with [`to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-to_i) or [`to_f`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-to_f):

```
subtotal = gets.to_f # Or gets.to_i
```

You won't need the [`chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-chomp) if you use `to_i` or `to_f`, those methods will ignore the trailing whitespace on their own.

That should give you a sensible value in `tax`.

Comment: <Chapter 1. X } } *chomp chomp*

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: What are you talking about?

Comment: Basically, `taxrate = gets.to_i` returns an integer, resulting in a proper output.  There's no unintuitive/'virtually never desired' newline added to the end of the integer, as in strings.

Comment: THAT'S MY LINE!!!  But hey, do you know how I can test to see if the program is breaking at `print`, `gets`, or `puts`?

Comment: Maybe I'm "drunk" or maybe you're slow. ^^  The question is where the input becomes a string: is at the `print` statement, at the `gets` statement, or elsewhere?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: `gets` gives you a string. Perhaps some time with the documentation would be helpful: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/

Comment: Obviously.  What I was saying in my initial response was: I'm on chapter 1 of the documentation that comes packaged with Ruby.  Imagine you're teaching English to someone who doesn't know the alphabet and can only say "hello".  When other readers encounter this question, they'll likely be in the same place I'm at, and they'll just re-ask the question.  No offense intended because I know it's frustrating to write things in a very simple way.  I got about 25% of it, though, which was enough to understand what I stated in my second comment.  Expecting more than that, now, is unrealistic.

Comment: Thanks for the doc links, also, btw.  Well-referenced.  +1.  I'll get your question a +1 when my downvote expires, too. :)

Comment: Aw, man!  The system boned me.  I can't undo my dvote.  I'll get you on another question, I guess. *toil* X,(